# Ubuntu. Почему автоматически сбрасывается пароль пользователя?

Tags: ubuntu, пароль

Сеанс SSH доступа к виртуальной машине с ОС `Ubuntu` посредством клиента KiTTY. По прошествии некоторого времени бездействия сбрасывается пароль текущего пользователя.

**Выглядит следующим образом:**
При возобновлении действий в текущем сеансе KiTTY, обычно он просыпается и снова входит в ОС автоматически. А теперь с некоторых пор не входит по причине `Access denied`, т.е. пароль пользователя либо изменен либо сброшен, т.к. любые команды с `sudo` не проходят по той же причине. Пустой пароль также не проходит.

Изменений никаких в ОС не проводилось.

После однократного случая пароль пользователя был перезадан через root. Но после засыпания и возврата в KiTTY-сеанс, примерно через сутки, снова был сброшен.

Не пойму, что происходит в системе..

Нормальная ли это практика при некоторых стандартных настройках ОС?
Как такие действия можно проверить?

Comment: Т.е. как сброшен? А если в новом сеансе залогиниться? Тоже пароль не поедет?

Comment: Именно. Похоже, что кто-то залогинился под root и поменял пароль. Можно ли это проверить в логах системы?

Comment: Ну начни с комманды `last`.

Comment: Вообще, правильная ли практика отключать SSH root-доступ к виртуальной машине и входить под обычным пользователем?

Comment: Стоп. Так ты под root логинишься что ли? О_о

Comment: Только для операции смены пароля. В остальные сеансы под обычным пользователем. Просто, root-доступ не отключен пока.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128520/discussion-between-jblack-and-don-rumata).